# Mariadb query variable with null value returns nothing

Tags: mariadb

I'm trying to select some rows when a specific column are equal to my variable.
Some of these rows have that column set as null.

For this, i made a query using a variable to get that match

```
SELECT

MT.Column1, 
MT.Column2, 
MT.SpecificColumn

FROM

MyTable MT

WHERE

MT.SpecificColumn = :Variable
```

So, it happens that when this variable receives NULL, the query doesn't return the rows that have the SpecificColumn value NULL.

The only way i got the rows was using this condition:

```
WHERE

MT.SpecificColumn IS NULL
```

but that case doesn't fit to me, because i need it to be dynamic.

Comment: So make the column “not null”

Comment: In some cases it will be null, and that is expected. What i need is to get the rows with that null column when i try to match the variable set as null with the column.

Comment: Check the null safe operator: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/null-safe-equal/

Comment: How badly does it harm query execution if you COALESCE both sides of the WHERE predicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Codd's rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules)

**Systematic treatment of null values**:

Null values (distinct from the empty character string or a string of blank characters and distinct from zero or any other number) are supported in fully relational DBMS for representing missing information and inapplicable information in a systematic way, independent of data type.

So you cannot compare missing data, but you can check if data is missing.

If you want to check NULL without IS NULL, you need to transform it, e.g.

`SELECT fields FROM MyTABLE WHERE IFNULL(MT.SpecificColumn, "NULL VALUE")=@variable`

If you set `@variable="NULL VALUE"` it will find the NULL values. If it's effective or not is of course another question.